# STM32 Interrupt

Tags: stm32, interrupt

I want to enable the SYSCFG clock of STM32WB55RGV6, but when I look reference manual SYSCFG is on the APB2 BUS, I want to enable SYSCFG using RCC → AP2ENR but SYSCFG but it is not there.

What should I do? Board: Nucleo WB55

Memory map and register boundary addresses:
[image: addresses]

RCC APB2 peripheral clock enables register:
[image: RCC_APB2ENR)]

I try to use interrupt without enabling the SYSCFG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only information I could find to do with this is in section 18.3.3 of the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0434-multiprotocol-wireless-32bit-mcu-armbased-cortexm4-with-fpu-bluetooth-lowenergy-and-802154-radio-solution-stmicroelectronics.pdf) is says:

```
The COMP clock provided by the clock controller is synchronous with
the APB2 clock.  There is no clock enable control bit provided in 
the RCC controller. Reset and clock enable bits are common for COMP
and SYSCFG.
```

So the clock for SYCFG is shared with the comparator modules, and it cannot be turned on or off.

Also there is nothing in the HAL or LL library to turn it on or off (where the would be for other STM32 families), so I think you can safely assume that the clock is always on.

Comment: Than you so much